# How to upload Files and Other fields with Request Body in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, dto

I want to upload three fields like:

Example Data:

```
partner_id: 3638,
review: [{'product_id': 155, 'order_sku_id': 155, 'review_title': 'Orange Review','rating': 5 }],
review_images[0][0]: ImageFile00
review_images[0][1]: ImageFile01
review_images[1][0]: ImageFile10
```

**review_images** is a array of images like the above.

My approach to upload these data. I have created a `Dto`:

```
export class CreateReviewDto {
    partner_id : Number;
    review: any[];
    review_images: any[];
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller('api/v1')
export class ReviewController {
  constructor(private readonly reviewService: ReviewService) {}

  @Post('/review')
  @HttpCode(201)
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('review_images[]'))
  create(@Body() createReviewDto: CreateReviewDto, @UploadedFiles() review_images: Express.Multer.File) {
    return this.reviewService.create(params,createReviewDto);
  }
}
```

But images are not coming in POSTMAN. Giving `undefined` Am I going to a right way? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I noticed. You should use 'review_images' in your FilesInterceptor ([link on documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#array-of-files))

```
@Controller('api/v1')
export class ReviewController {
  constructor(private readonly reviewService: ReviewService) {}

  @Post('/review')
  @HttpCode(201)
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('review_images'))
  create(@Body() createReviewDto: CreateReviewDto, @UploadedFiles() review_images: Express.Multer.File) {
    return this.reviewService.create(params,createReviewDto);
  }
}
```

The second thing. You should send the right request from postman. I suppose it should look like this
[image]

Comment: But he mentioned 2D array.